# Pandas Function similar to SQL rank and partition

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle

I have the below data

```
ID        DD         DAYS   VALUE
 1     08-MAR-19      4      500
 1     09-MAR-19      1      1500
 2     13-MAR-19      0       0
```

I want to select the maximum number of days like for ID 1 it will only return the row with 4.
In SQL I use the below query

```
select aa.*, rank() over (partition by ID order by DAYS desc) rank_n;
```

Which returns only

```
 ID        DD         DAYS   VALUE 
    1     08-MAR-19      4       500
    2     13-MAR-19      0       0
```

how can I do the same in pandas

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `loc` which is used for the old `select` function in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id':[1,1,4],'DD':['08-MAR-19','09-MAR-19','13-MAR-19'],'DAYS':[4,1,0],'VALUE':[500,1500,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.loc[(df['id'] == 1) & (df['DAYS'] == max(df['DAYS']))]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id         DD  DAYS  VALUE
0   1  08-MAR-19     4    500
```

Comment: the data has many IDs that was just a sample, I therefore can't filter using df['id'] == 1

Comment: Then you should use a groupby and keep the index values.However if you wish to partition by `id` why is the `id` 2 not showing up?

Comment: sorry it should show, I have amended the question